# Add generated value to a RealmObject

Tags: realm, kotlin

I've created a model in Realm as follows:

```
 
open class Contact() : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Required
    open var id: String = ""

    @Required
    @Index
    open var firstName: String = ""
    @Required
    @Index
    open var lastName: String = ""
    @Required
    @Index
    open var fullName: String = ""

    ...
}
```

How would one generate the `fullName` when updating an object?

I know for instance in CoreData you could mutate a property when `willSave:_` gets invoked. How would this work for Realm?

I tried providing a getter, but this will break `RealmObject`'s behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: If fullName is the concatenation of firstName and lastName, why store it in the first place instead of just computing it from the two other fields? If not, then why exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: fullName is not always used as a concatenation. It a way to search over the whole name, for instance in a "search all" box. In the rest of the implementation firstName and lastName is always used separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [custom setters in `RealmObject`s](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models)

```
@Required
@Index
open var firstName: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        updateFullName()
    }

@Required
@Index
open var lastName: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        updateFullName()
    }

private fun updateFullName() {
    fullName = "$firstName $lastName"
}

@Required
@Index
open var fullName: String = ""
```

Comment: Awesome, that works! I forgot to mention, but I also tried this one, but did't know about `field = value`, so now it works!